Unable to fetch data from the expo-sqlite database efficiently
This is a function to get the data for a bar chart in my expo application using expo-sqlite but the sql query doesn't seem to work properly.
What i wanted was to create a function that can fetch the data of total sales done in this current month with previous 4 month's together. And in case the data is not present, the month name will be passed and the data will be 0.
The Table Query:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sales (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,name TEXT NOT NULL,quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,soldPrice REAL NOT NULL,date TEXT NOT NULL);
The Sql Query:
WITH months AS (
        SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', date('now', '-5 months', '+' || n || ' months')) AS month 
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4)
    ) 
    SELECT 
        CASE strftime('%m', m.month) 
            WHEN '01' THEN 'Jan' 
            WHEN '02' THEN 'Feb' 
            WHEN '03' THEN 'Mar' 
            WHEN '04' THEN 'Apr' 
            WHEN '05' THEN 'May' 
            WHEN '06' THEN 'Jun' 
            WHEN '07' THEN 'Jul' 
            WHEN '08' THEN 'Aug' 
            WHEN '09' THEN 'Sep' 
            WHEN '10' THEN 'Oct' 
            WHEN '11' THEN 'Nov' 
            WHEN '12' THEN 'Dec' 
        END AS month, 
        COALESCE(SUM(s.soldPrice * s.quantity), 0) AS total_sales_amount 
    FROM months m 
    LEFT JOIN Sales s ON strftime('%Y-%m', s.date) = m.month 
    GROUP BY m.month 
    ORDER BY m.month;

The Chart data Function:
import * as Sqlite from 'expo-sqlite;

const db = Sqlite.openDatabaseSync('test.db');


const ChartData = async () => {
    const labels = [];
    const dataset = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; 

    const query = `
    WITH months AS (
        SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', date('now', '-5 months', '+' || n || ' months')) AS month 
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4)
    ) 
    SELECT 
        CASE strftime('%m', m.month) 
            WHEN '01' THEN 'Jan' 
            WHEN '02' THEN 'Feb' 
            WHEN '03' THEN 'Mar' 
            WHEN '04' THEN 'Apr' 
            WHEN '05' THEN 'May' 
            WHEN '06' THEN 'Jun' 
            WHEN '07' THEN 'Jul' 
            WHEN '08' THEN 'Aug' 
            WHEN '09' THEN 'Sep' 
            WHEN '10' THEN 'Oct' 
            WHEN '11' THEN 'Nov' 
            WHEN '12' THEN 'Dec' 
        END AS month, 
        COALESCE(SUM(s.soldPrice * s.quantity), 0) AS total_sales_amount 
    FROM months m 
    LEFT JOIN Sales s ON strftime('%Y-%m', s.date) = m.month 
    GROUP BY m.month 
    ORDER BY m.month;`;

    const results = await db.getAllAsync(query);
    console.log(results) // LOG: [{"month": null, "total_sales_amount": 0}, {"month": null, "total_sales_amount": 0}, {"month": null, "total_sales_amount": 0}, {"month": null, "total_sales_amount": 0}, {"month": null, "total_sales_amount": 0}]

    if (results && results.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            const row = results[i];
            labels.push(row.month);
            dataset[i] = row.total_sales_amount;
        }
    } else {
        const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const currentMonthIndex = currentDate.getMonth();

        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            const monthIndex = (currentMonthIndex - i + 12) % 12;
            labels.unshift(monthNames[monthIndex]);
            dataset.unshift(0);  // Initialize dataset for these months
        }
    }

    console.log(labels, dataset); //LOG: dataset:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], labels: [null, null, null, null, null]}
    return [labels, dataset];
};

The result:
[{"month": null, "total_sales_amount": 0}, {"month": null, "total_sales_amount": 0}, {"month": null, "total_sales_amount": 0}, {"month": null, "total_sales_amount": 0}, {"month": null , "total_sales_amount": 0}]
I thought that if the sql query can do it, it would be efficient, so is there any other alternative way to achive this efficiently.
I tried to break down the process and do it bit by bit but it slowed down the process a lot.

m.month is not a date, so strftime('%m', m.month) (string from time) will yield null. Try using substr instead:
WITH months AS (
        SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', date('now', '-5 months', '+' || n || ' months')) AS month 
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4)
    ) 
    SELECT 
        CASE substr(m.month, 6)
            WHEN '01' THEN 'Jan' 
            WHEN '02' THEN 'Feb' 
            WHEN '03' THEN 'Mar' 
            WHEN '04' THEN 'Apr' 
            WHEN '05' THEN 'May' 
            WHEN '06' THEN 'Jun' 
            WHEN '07' THEN 'Jul' 
            WHEN '08' THEN 'Aug' 
            WHEN '09' THEN 'Sep' 
            WHEN '10' THEN 'Oct' 
            WHEN '11' THEN 'Nov' 
            WHEN '12' THEN 'Dec' 
        END AS month, 
        COALESCE(SUM(s.soldPrice * s.quantity), 0) AS total_sales_amount 
    FROM months m 
    LEFT JOIN Sales s ON strftime('%Y-%m', s.date) = m.month 
    GROUP BY m.month 
    ORDER BY m.month;

